# Why hudson/jenkins tries to make commit?

Tags: git, maven, hudson, jenkins

I'm using Hudson to clone a Git repository and build it. I'm getting the following error:

```
FATAL: Could not apply tag jenkins-mus-tomcat-2-2
hudson.plugins.git.GitException: Could not apply tag jenkins-mus-tomcat-2-2
```

It's strange because I don't want Hudson to make any commits. It should only pull and compile.

What's the problem and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Check "Skip internal tag" config under "Advanced..." in section "Source code management".

It will skip the tagging.

Answer (score 2):

Note: the [Hudson bug 3874](http://issues.hudson-ci.org/browse/HUDSON-3874) mentions:

> tagging fails if there's no `~/.gitconfig`, and you get the following error:

```
workspace] $ git tag -a -f -m "Hudson Build #34" hudson-JAMCircle-34
FATAL: Could not apply tag hudson-JAMCircle-34
```

Make sure you have a HOME defined for the user running the Hudson process, and make sure there is a `.gitconfig`, with at least [user.name](http://adhockery.blogspot.com/2009/11/git-and-hudson.html) defined in it (See this [blog post for instance](http://adhockery.blogspot.com/2009/11/git-and-hudson.html)).
If needed, configure those variables within Hudson itself through `GIT_COMMITTER_NAME`, `GIT_COMMITTER_EMAIL`, `GIT_AUTHOR_NAME` and `GIT_AUTHOR_EMAIL` environment variables (Cf [this example](http://kb.k-metamodule.com/logiciel/hudson-logiciel/configurer-git-dans-hudson/131/)).

---

That being said, considering the [issue HUDSON-5676](http://issues.hudson-ci.org/browse/HUDSON-5676) , you should have an option "Tag every build automatically" that you can change to unchecked, in order to avoid the tag entirely.