# Jenkins + git: "tell me who you are" error, why does it need to tag?

Tags: git, jenkins, jenkins-plugins

Just installed Jenkins in Ubuntu 12.04 and I wanted to create a simple build that just clones a project and builds it.

It fails because it cannot tag. It cannot tag because it errors out saying "**tell me who you are**" apparently because I didn't set git settings UserName and UserEmail.

But, I should not need to set those, Jenkins is going to just clone the repository, why does it need the credentials if it's not going to push changes, why does it need to do a tag at all?

Full error log is:

```
Started by user anonymous
Checkout:workspace / /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/Foo.Bar.Baz/workspace - hudson.remoting.LocalChannel@38e609c9
Using strategy: Default
Cloning the remote Git repository
Cloning repository origin
Fetching upstream changes from git@mygithost.mydomain.local:foo-bar-baz/foo-bar-baz.git
Seen branch in repository origin/1.0
Seen branch in repository origin/1.5.4
Seen branch in repository origin/HEAD
Seen branch in repository origin/master
Commencing build of Revision 479d37776b46283a946dd395c1ea78f18c0b97c7 (origin/1.0)
Checking out Revision 479d37776b46283a946dd395c1ea78f18c0b97c7 (origin/1.0)
FATAL: Could not apply tag jenkins-Foo.Bar.Baz-2
hudson.plugins.git.GitException: Could not apply tag jenkins-Foo.Bar.Baz-2
at hudson.plugins.git.GitAPI.tag(GitAPI.java:737)
at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM$4.invoke(GitSCM.java:1320)
at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM$4.invoke(GitSCM.java:1268)
at hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:758)
at hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:740)
at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.checkout(GitSCM.java:1268)
at hudson.model.AbstractProject.checkout(AbstractProject.java:1193)
at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractRunner.checkout(AbstractBuild.java:565)
at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractRunner.run(AbstractBuild.java:453)
at hudson.model.Run.run(Run.java:1376)
at hudson.matrix.MatrixBuild.run(MatrixBuild.java:220)
at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:88)
at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:175)
at hudson.model.OneOffExecutor.run(OneOffExecutor.java:66)
Caused by: hudson.plugins.git.GitException: Command "git tag -a -f -m Jenkins Build #2 jenkins-Foo.Bar.Baz-2" returned status code 128:
stdout: 
stderr: 
*** Please tell me who you are.

    Run

  git config --global user.email "you@example.com"
  git config --global user.name "Your Name"

to set your account's default identity.
Omit --global to set the identity only in this repository.

fatal: empty ident  <jenkins@somehostname.(none)> not allowed

    at hudson.plugins.git.GitAPI.launchCommandIn(GitAPI.java:786)
    at hudson.plugins.git.GitAPI.launchCommand(GitAPI.java:748)
    at hudson.plugins.git.GitAPI.launchCommand(GitAPI.java:758)
    at hudson.plugins.git.GitAPI.tag(GitAPI.java:735)
    ... 13 more
```

Comment: Huh! After configuring user.name and user.email, the build succeeded but it has created a new tag in the server called "1.0", why is git plugin so weird in the default configuration and how to configure it so it doesn't do this?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

The idea of tagging when pulling/cloning a repo is common to most Build Scheduler out there:
Hudson-Jenkins, but also [CruiseControl](http://cruisecontrol.sourceforge.net/main/) (The build label determined by the `labelincrementer`), or [RTC Jazz Build Engine (where they are called "snapshots")](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/rtc/v1r0m0/topic/com.ibm.team.scm.doc/topics/c_snapshots.html).

The idea is to set a persistent record of the *input* to a build.
That way, the code you are pulling, even if it wasn't tagged, is tagged automatically for you by the build scheduler, in order to be able to get back to that specific build later.

If that policy (always tagging before a build) is set, then Jenkins will need to know who you are in order to make a git tag (it is a git object with an author attached to it: `user.name` and `user.email`).

However, as mentioned in " [Why hudson/jenkins tries to make commit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6980570/why-hudson-jenkins-tries-to-make-commit) ":

> Checks "`Skip internal tag`" config under "`Advanced...`" in section "`Source code management`".

That should avoid that extra tagging step you appear to not need.

[image]

Comment: @knocte yes... I was a bit slow on that one ;)

Comment: I thought that screenshot looked familiar :)

Comment: I don't have most of that screen. I can only set a repository URL, name and refspec. Is this for a specific version of Jenkins? We have 1.412. Or do I need a specific plugin?

Comment: @AmedeeVanGasse it was from the plugin from 2+ years ago. Not sure how it looks today.

Comment: 1.412 was released on 16-May-2011, 3.5 years ago.

Comment: @AmedeeVanGasse I was referring to the version of the Jenkisn Git plugin, not the version of Jenkins.

Comment: OK. That is version 1.1.9. I can't find a date, but it's probably of the same age.

Comment: @AmedeeVanGasse 1.1.9 means May 16yh, 2011: https://github.com/jenkinsci/git-plugin/releases/tag/git-1.1.9. At the time, I was looking at probably 1.1.19: https://github.com/jenkinsci/git-plugin/releases/tag/git-1.1.19. The release notes at https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Git+Plugin can give you an idea of the delta between the two in term of features.

Comment: Thanks. In any case it looks like our Jenkins and plugins are quite ancient.

Answer (score 30):

As for how to set user.email and user.name,
In jenkins, go to "Manage Jenkins" > "Configure System"
and scroll down to "Git plugin" and there you will find
[image: Git plugin screen shot]

enter your email and name, you're good to go.

Comment: I have that set, but it doesn't appear to be used.

Comment: A alternative option if you have limited Jenkins admin access would be to Add "Additional behavior" in the Git plugin section of the job configuration. You can select the additional behavior to add custom user name/email address that will only be applicable to your job and not a global setting.

Answer (score 3):

I used the solution above by iecanfly . Using my git user name and password didnt work  , I 
entered

username : jenkins

email : jenkins@localhost

That fixed the issue.

Answer (score 1):

You can also SSH into Jenkins and navigate over to the workspace directory, and then you can just run the git config user.name and user.email commands normally.

Comment: I can't SSH into Jenkins due to restrictions by our server hosting.

Comment: I can SSH, and git work in command line, but not in Jenkins. Solution from @iecanfly  seems working for me.

Answer (score 0):

If you are running Jenkins in a Docker container, you'd need to exec into the container `docker exec -it <CONTAINER_ID> sh` then run the suggested git commands with your email and name.